# What is a base64PublicEncodedKey?

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement in-app billing into my Android app.[The Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample) tells me that I need to use a base64PublicEncodedKey in order to use the IabHelper, however I do not understand what is meant to be typed here.

The code in the documentation:

```
IabHelper mHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// ...
String base64EncodedPublicKey;

// compute your public key and store it in base64EncodedPublicKey
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Vidal

Comment: That is your public key base64 encoded in a String.

Comment: '// compute your public key and store it in base64EncodedPublicKey'. So you compute your public key. Very probably that is a sequence of bytes. And if not then look in the documentation what you have to do exactly. After that encode the bytes array base64 to a String.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you know a way to create such a key? I can pretty much only program in java and not really in security

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the Base64 encoded RSA public key in your play store developer account. (Under Services and APIs)

You need to pass this to the IabHelper class.